# two similar questions about mentioning GRE score in CV for grad applications

Tags: discussion

[Can it hurt to put my GRE score on my resume?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56890/can-it-hurt-to-put-my-gre-score-on-my-resume)

[Put good GRE scores on resume submitted with grad app?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/57803/put-good-gre-scores-on-resume-submitted-with-grad-app)

I'm not sure what to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you ask if and how the questions should be marked as duplicates.

The questions are similar, but it's not clear that they are the same question. One asks if it can hurt to add a GRE score to the resume of an application for a field and school *that does not require the GRE*; the other question leaves it unclear if the GRE is required in the field - I read it as if it was -, and the question is if mentioning the score *in the resume* is advisable. I could be reading the intent of the second question incorrectly.

Academia SE is fairly low volume. Given that it is unclear to me that we here have two duplicate questions, I would rather not take any closing-as-duplicate action. If you feel strongly something should happen, and agree with my interpretation, I would instead consider a clarifying edit. The site doesn't have the immediacy to cut down on volume that stackoverflow or math SE might have. I personally advocate a less aggressive approach to close votes than is common there - only for obvious cases, or when it greatly helps later information retrieval.

Comment: I was assuming that in both cases the GRE wasn't explicitly requested.  I mean, if it were requested, then the score would be submitted in the standard way.  Part of what bothered me was that the answers weren't consistent between the two threads. / Is there some way of making a canonical / Community wki thing and refer visitors to it from both threads?

Comment: If you would like to just link the questions informally, I'd add a comment under the question(s), like " Related: (link)" or "see also; (link)".